# I am trying to download SVG content as PNG file. The above code is working fine in Chrome and Firefox browser. Not working on IE

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying to download SVG content as PNG file. The above code is working fine in Chrome and Firefox browser. Not working on IE. There is no errors in the browser console.

```
var svg = document.querySelector( "svg" );
var svgData = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString( svg );
var canvas = document.createElement( "canvas" );

var svgSize = svg.getBoundingClientRect();
canvas.width = svgSize.width;
canvas.height = svgSize.height;
var ctx = canvas.getContext( "2d" );
var img = document.createElement( "img" );
img.setAttribute( "src", "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + btoa( svgData ) );


img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage( img, 0, 0 );

    setTimeout(function(){
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.download = "networkmap.png";
        a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");console.log(a.href);
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
     }, 500);
};
```

Comment: Can you provide info about, which version of IE you used.

Comment: you can download a dataURL in IE with my download() tool: https://github.com/rndme/download eg,`download("data:text/plain,hello%20world", "dlDataUrlText.txt", "text/plain");`

Comment: I am using IE 11 Version